# WordPress- Username custom URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need to change the url from http://www.example.com/profiles/?userid=59 to http://www.example.com/profiles/username in WORDPRESS. How can i add username in url instead of user id. Anyone can help me ? Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the author/user profiles urls, changing your permalink structure to what you see below should do the trick.

```
%category%/%postname%
```

Edit: you can do this in settings > permalinks in the admin area. Sorry, forgot to include this before.